# C++ download file - if not available increasing RAM usage 1mb/s

Tags: c++, download, timeout

my Code keeps filling the RAM, if it cant reach the file to download.(network disabled to test)
How can I stop downloading after timeout?

here is the main part for downloading:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE instanceHandle, HINSTANCE, char*, int)
{
    using namespace std;
    std::wstring loadme = targetfolder;
    loadme += L"\\filename.txt";
    std::wstring url1(L"fileurl");
    HRESULT hr1 = URLDownloadToFile(NULL, (url1.c_str()), (loadme.c_str()), 0, NULL); //Download-Start
}
```

Comment: Use the last parameter: "For best control over the download and its progress, an IBindStatusCallback interface is recommended."  source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775123(v=vs.85).aspx  see the Remarks section.

Answer (score 1):

You can use WinINet functions to check if internet is available, check if url link is available, and report progress. Needs "wininet.lib"

[WinINet Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385483%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#include <fstream>

void geturl(const wchar_t *url)
{
    std::ofstream file("c:\\test\\test.htm");
    HINTERNET hopen = InternetOpen(L"myAppName",INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG,NULL,NULL,0);
    if (hopen)
    {
        HINTERNET hurl = InternetOpenUrl(hopen,url,NULL,0,INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE,0);
        if (hurl)
        {
            DWORD received;
            const int bufsize = 1024;
            char buf[bufsize];
            while (InternetReadFile(hurl, buf, bufsize, &received))
            {
                //progress...
                if (!received) break;
                file.write(buf, received);
            }
            InternetCloseHandle(hurl);
        }
        InternetCloseHandle(hopen);
    }
}
```